# listenTo on collection reset doesn't get invoked after collection is fetched

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, js-amd

Below is my initialization function of a view that should receive a module name when initialized in order to fetch the correct data from the collection.

The issue is:

1. Listento doesn't redirect to the render() method after the collection is fetched, also it gives me an error on the console

> TypeError: e is undefined

**What is the mistake i made with the code below??**

```
    initialize: function() {          

     var that = this;
        if(this.options.module === 'questions'){                  

            require([
                'app/collections/questions'
            ], function(QuestionsCollection){                   
                var moduleCollection = new QuestionsCollection();
                that.collection = moduleCollection;
                moduleCollection.fetch({
                    reset: true, 
                    success: function(){},
                    error: function(){}
                    });                                                                        
            });                

        }

        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
        this.listenTo(Backbone, 'close:Home', this.close);
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is `riquire.js`, when you write `require([/*jsFile*/], callback);` the call to `callback` is made asynchronously after the `jsFile` is loaded. So when you call `require([...` immediatly after that you call `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);` and at the time this last line is executed the `jsFile` is not yet loaded and the `callback` is not yet called thus the `this.collection` is undefined.

Take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/ZZuGC/1/ and the order the `console.log('require');` & `console.log('listenTo');` are printed to the console.

---

I think that the solution to your problem is as follows :

```
initialize: function() {          

 var that = this;
    if(this.options.module === 'questions'){                  

        require([
            'app/collections/questions'
        ], function(QuestionsCollection){                   
            var moduleCollection = new QuestionsCollection();

            that.collection = moduleCollection;
            // here is my suggestion
            that.listenTo(that.collection, 'reset', that.render);

            moduleCollection.fetch({
                reset: true, 
                success: function(){},
                error: function(){}
                });                                                                        
        });                

    }
    this.listenTo(Backbone, 'close:Home', this.close);
},
```

I have updated the example http://jsfiddle.net/ZZuGC/2/

Comment: I am convinced with your analysis to the problem, but how do you suggest to to do in such a situation, I used this solution to reduce the number of files loaded from the server by the request only.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a scope issue where the require module is in a closure. Try the following:

```
initialize: function() {          

 var that = this;
    if(this.options.module === 'questions'){                  

        require([
            'app/collections/questions'
        ], function(QuestionsCollection){                   
            var moduleCollection = new QuestionsCollection();
            moduleCollection.fetch({
                reset: true, 
                success: function(){},
                error: function(){}
                });
            that.listenTo(moduleCollection, 'reset', that.render);                                                    
        });                
    }

    this.listenTo(Backbone, 'close:Home', this.close);  
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for, I was thinking that it may be scope issue and did a lot of solutions including the one you just mentioned, but seems that it's not the problem, think that answer of Rida is closer to solve it, Do you?